# Get GCM end point by device

Tags: push-notification, google-cloud-messaging, firebase-cloud-messaging

Is there a possible way of differentiating end points by device type? I would like to filter mobile device subscriptions if possible?

Comment: Hi Naughty Ninja. I'm sorry, but I'm a bit confused, do you want to determine if the specific recipient(s)' device type (Android/iOS)?

Comment: @AL. In simple words, I wanna allow users to turn off and on specific notifications for specific devices, does that make more sense?

Comment: Yup. That's better.

Answer (score 0):

There is currently no built-in function to turn on/off notifications based on the device type for GCM or FCM.

As a workaround, you could make use of *topic messaging*, having an `Android` and `iOS` topic. However, depending on your use case, this might not be an option.

You could instead store the tokens along with a device type in your App Server (e.g. `token:aaa, deviceType:Android`) and include/remove it from the target(s) accordingly.